# Front page is not loading - tag search error

Tags: bug, tag-search

The front page of [Chinese Stack Exchange](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/) wasn't loading yesterday for a good five minutes with the following error message:

> [image: Error message for tag search]

> It was not possible to perform this tag search at this time due to an unexpected error.

What's that about?

Comment: *wasn't loading yesterday:* Is it working fine now?

Comment: Yeah it was fine after about five min. Looks like a dupe.

Comment: Such bugs should be reported when they happen, not much point in reporting them after they're fixed.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask I don't find a problem with reporting those, I think it's fine. The only issue with this report was that it was already reported (i.e. a duplicate).

Comment: @Sonic I'd agree for long down time (e.g. hour or more) then it's fine to ask for explanation even long time after it's up again, however, short down times are common, and IMO don't require post mortem.